# Using Groupby and Orderby on same query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
( 
  SELECT com_jobcard.job_card_num, 
    sum( worked_qty ),employee.emp_name
  FROM timer_completed
  INNER JOIN process ON process.id = timer_completed.process_id
  INNER JOIN com_jobcard ON com_jobcard.id = timer_completed.job_card_id
  INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = timer_completed.employee_id
                                   AND process.id = '611'
                                   AND timer_completed.group_id = '60'
    AND timer_completed.report_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
  ORDER BY com_jobcard.id DESC 
) AS tmp_table 
GROUP BY com_jobcard.job_card_num
```

In this code I'm using `Group by` option but I need the result in descending order of `com_jobcard.id` if  I use the above query it returns:

> `#1054` - Unknown column 'com_jobcard.job_card_num' in 'group
>   statement' .

please help me .

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Your query is not really valid SQL.  Even if you can get MySQL to accept it, your query uses a (mis)feature where MySQL allows any columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`.  So, a column such as `emp_name` gets an *indeterminate* value.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
GROUP BY tmp_table.job_card_num
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things: 
1) All Columns in the Sub Query need to be Named. This will clear error #1054

```
sum( worked_qty ) as 'WorkedTotal'
```

2) Order by is only available in Subqueries if you are using the 'Top Select' clause . You will need to use Order by Where you have group by and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You're unnecessarily nesting your query here.  You can order an aggregate query result set by putting the `ORDER BY` after the `GROUP BY`.  Also, like Gordon pointed out in his comment, you're abusing the nonstandard MySql extension to `GROUP BY`. This will make you crazy unless you learn about it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Try refactoring your query like this:

```
SELECT com_jobcard.job_card_num, 
        sum( worked_qty),
        employee.emp_name,
        com_jobcard.id
   FROM timer_completed
   JOIN process ON process.id = timer_completed.process_id
   JOIN com_jobcard ON com_jobcard.id = timer_completed.job_card_id
   JOIN employee ON employee.id = timer_completed.employee_id
                AND process.id = '611'
                AND timer_completed.group_id = '60'
                AND timer_completed.report_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
  GROUP BY com_jobcard.job_card_num,  employee.emp_name, com_jobcard.id
  ORDER BY com_jobcard.id DESC
```

Besides being simpler than your proposed query, this handles `GROUP BY` correctly and yields the order you've specified.